# Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

At run-time server error showing in webbrowser regarding **Unrecognized escape sequence** .

**Error Description:**

> Server Error in '/image11' Application. Compilation Error Description:
>   An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

**Source Error:**

```
Line 21:     public void getcon()
Line 22:     {
Line 23:         con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUNDADAN\Documents\..mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
Line 24:         con.Open();
Line 25:     }


Source File: d:\MY .Net(RuleZZ)\image11\App_Code\Class1.cs    Line: 23


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:
```

Comment: "still i getting error" is not a problem description. What "error" are you getting? We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, so you must provide that information in your question. You have the information about the error; you need to provide it to us as well if you want help.

Comment: Tell me - you *are* going to put that connection string into a config file, yes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUNDADAN\Documents\..mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

This is wrong
Try this

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUNDADAN\Documents\..mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

or

```
 con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\MUNDADAN\\Documents\\..mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Comment: is error same as last error ?last error was because of `\` in your con str

Comment: and with this how `con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\MUNDADAN\\Documents\\..mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

Comment: mark as answer if it was working dude ;)